# How can I know if there is a restaurant at given latitude and longitude location?

Tags: google-maps, foursquare, google-places, yelp

How do I know if there is a restaurant at a given lat-long location?

Can we use google maps/ google places/ Yelp/ FourSquare for the same?

**Input** : lat, long pair ( 1.280634,103.845392 )

**Output** : Meii Sushi

Comment: You can use Google API.

Comment: can you give more details about which google API to use

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/search) and search for venues at that location with the following request. Just pass your latitude & longitude in the `ll` param and set the radius around that point in meters in the `radius` param.

```
GET https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=44.3,37.2&radius=200
```

With the `categories` field that is provided in the response you can check whether the place is a restaurant or not